# Maximum liters capacity (petrol,diesel) for a four wheeler Car

Tags: car, diesel, gasoline

Can you specify the maximum liters capacity in petrol fuel  input of a four wheeler car for any make & model?

Can the maximum liter capacity of that four wheeler car make & model be increased further?

As a example say 50 liters maximum petrol fuel input.

Can this be further increased?
If No, Why?

What are the different parameters for taking into consideration the maximum liter capacity of a four wheeler?

Example : Engine redesign & construction.

Similarly for Diesel fuel the maximum liter capacity of the specific car make & model.

Can we evaluate different Cylinder shapes, prisms for the structure where the fuel petrol or diesel is added?

https://www.google.com/search?q=gallon+to+liter&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AOaemvKHKj0Lz4b6-pVFFoyuwMtbFx82mw%3A1632453847000&source=hp&ei=1kRNYaimOruWjgbwoLj4Bg&oq=gallon+to+li&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQARgBMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggjEO8DEOoCECc6BwgjEO8DECc6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOggIABCABBCxA1DZD1iwO2DZWWgBcAB4AIAB1gSIAdAYkgELMC43LjEuMi4wLjKYAQCgAQGwAQU&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a good answer for this.  Not only is it vague, your first question seems to require knowing all makes & models on earth.  You can certainly use Google to find the specific capacity of any car but I doubt all of them in one place.  Can capacity be increased?  Yes, most certainly you can buy auxiliary tanks for many 4wds, some OEM, some after market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, on a Landrover you could ask for 3 fuel tanks, two of 10 gallons and one of 16 for a total of 36 gallons.

Usually only specified by the military, but some ordinary customers did specify the two 10 gallon tanks.

Then it was also possible to do custom tanks for more storage and racks for jerrycans...

Comment: Thanks Mike. So 36 gallons is 136 liters. Can we further increase the Maximum liters capacity? i.e. say 50 gallons. We have to redesign Engine for the same?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar So the last line says custom tanks and jerrycans… what more do you want? Surely the language was clear?